# How to handle foreign addresses in Java application that calls Nominatim Webservice

Tags: java, encoding, openstreetmap, nominatim

The following code produces a string that has question marks as the display name when I insert an Iranian address(?????, ???????). However if I put the same url into my browser, it returns Tehran, Iran instead of question marks. I know that it has something to do with encoding but how do I get the English text as the browser returns in my java application?

```
String rawAddress = "Tehran";
String address = URLEncoder.encode(rawAddress, "utf-8");
String geocodeURL = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=1&polygon=0&addressdetails=0&email=myemail@gmail.com&languagecodes=en&q=";

String formattedUrl = geocodeURL + address;
URL theGeocodeUrl = new URL(formattedUrl);
System.out.println("HERE " +theGeocodeUrl.toString());
InputStream is = theGeocodeUrl.openStream();

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

final List<Object> dealData = mapper.readValue(is, List.class);
System.out.println(dealData.get(0).toString());
```

I tried the following code but it produced this: ØªÙ‡Ø±Ø§Ù†, â€?Ø§ÙŠØ±Ø§Ù†â€Ž for the display name which should be Tehran, Iran.

```
System.out.println(new String(dealData.get(0).toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: What URL are you retrieving exactly? Is it https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=1&polygon=0&addressdetails=0&email=myemail@gmail.com&languagecodes=en&q=Tehran or a different one? Can you show us the HTTP request you are sending and the response you are retrieving? You can capture it using wireshark or tcpdump.

Comment: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=1&polygon=0&addressdetails=0&email=myemail@gmail.com&languagecodes=en&q=Tehran returns: {place_id=125561, licence=Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright, osm_type=node, osm_id=25960293, boundingbox=[35.526172, 35.846172, 51.2623519, 51.5823519], lat=35.686172, lon=51.4223519, display_name=?????, ???????, class=place, type=city, importance=0.68426133004096, icon=http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_place_city.p.20.png}

Comment: @scai - I captured it in wireshark and it displays as question marks where it should be Tehran, Iran. What part of the capture do you want to see?

Comment: This URL works fine here and the response contains `"display_name":"Teheran, Iran"`. Must be a local problem. I'm afraid I don't know the source of your problem.

Comment: Did you run it in java? It works fine if I put it in my browser but if I run the code above in java it returns question marks?

Comment: No, I did just run it in my browser.

Try to compare the HTTP requests and response of your browser and your java application. Especially the HTTP request and response headers.

Comment: Try using "accept-language" rather than "languagecodes" as the name of the URL parameter for Nominatim?

Comment: @headuck  You are correct! It works! Thank you so much! Please answer the question so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "accept-language" in the URL parameter for Nominatim to specify the preferred language of Nominatim's results, overriding whatever default the HTTP header may set.  From the documentation:

> accept-language= <browser language string>
>
> Preferred language order for showing search results,  overrides the
>   value specified in the "Accept-Language" HTTP header. Either uses
>   standard rfc2616 accept-language string or a simple comma separated
>   list of language codes.